# Tag design in android using single textview and array of data

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am new to android programming and I want to achieve this in my android app:

[image]

My JSON is this:

```
"Keywords":["medical","science","international"],
```

and my Android code is this:

```
String keyStr = ""; 
for (String str : m.getKeywords())  
{           
    keyStr += str + " ";         
}
```

When I put it into my `TextView`, it shows the results like:

> medical science international

But, I want to give it the effect it is shown in the above picture, which I did in my website. One solution was to use `HTML.fromhtml()` but it is not working for me, I need any other solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each tag could be remove with the cross on their right, you have to create multiple `TextView`s and each `ImageView`s should have `onClickListener`.

From my point of view, it could be a lot of tags rendering in a small width screen, so I'd use a `HorizontalScrollView`. So you could create a container:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tags_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And regarding the number of tags, do a loop to create dynamically each tag, as follows:

```
LinearLayout tagsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tags_container);

for (String keyword : m.getKeywords()) { 
    // inflate the child view by using a custom layout
    View tagView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tag_layout, null);
    TextView tagTextview = (TextView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tags_textview);
    ImageView tagImageview = (ImageView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tags_imageview);

    // set the elements value
    tagTextView.setText(keyword);
    tagImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // close the tag
    }
    // add to the container
    tagsContainer.addView(tagView);          
}
```